# Can not install Kali Linux headers

Tags: kali-linux

I am trying to install Linux headers for Kali Linux on my machine and I have tried every possible solution on the internet but it always show "Unable to locate packages";
I'm following the instructions from: [TP-Link Archer T2U Plus a.k.a AC600 High-Gain](https://github.com/nlkguy/archer-t2u-plus-linux)

```
└─# sudo apt install build-essential libelf-dev linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-6.1.0-kali9-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-6.1.0-kali9-amd64'
```

I tried to find correct version by command:

```
apt-cache search linux-headers
```

And there is what I see:

```
linux-headers-6.3.0-kali1-amd64 - Header files for Linux 6.3.0-kali1-amd64
linux-headers-6.3.0-kali1-cloud-amd64 - Header files for Linux 6.3.0-kali1-cloud-amd64
linux-headers-6.3.0-kali1-common - Common header files for Linux 6.3.0-kali1
linux-headers-6.3.0-kali1-common-rt - Common header files for Linux 6.3.0-kali1-rt
linux-headers-6.3.0-kali1-rt-amd64 - Header files for Linux 6.3.0-kali1-rt-amd64
linux-headers-amd64 - Header files for Linux amd64 configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-cloud-amd64 - Header files for Linux cloud-amd64 configuration (meta-   package)
linux-headers-rt-amd64 - Header files for Linux rt-amd64 configuration (meta-package)
linux-libc-dev-alpha-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-amd64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-arc-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-arm64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-armel-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-armhf-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-hppa-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-i386-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-m68k-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mips-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mips64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mips64el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mips64r6-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mips64r6el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsel-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsn32-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsn32el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsn32r6-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsn32r6el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsr6-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsr6el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-powerpc-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-ppc64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-ppc64el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-riscv64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-s390x-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-sh4-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-sparc64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-x32-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
```

uname -r:

```
6.1.0-kali9-amd64
```

one of the next step like:

```
sudo make dkms_install
```

Gave me an error:

```
cp -r * /usr/src/8812au-5.6.4.2_35491.20191025
dkms add -m 8812au -v 5.6.4.2_35491.20191025
Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/source -> /usr/src/8812au-5.6.4.2_35491.20191025
dkms build -m 8812au -v 5.6.4.2_35491.20191025
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 6.1.0-kali9-amd64 cannot be found at /lib/modules/6.1.0-kali9-amd64/build or /lib/modules/6.1.0-kali9-amd64/source.
Please install the linux-headers-6.1.0-kali9-amd64 package or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located.
make: *** [Makefile:1786: dkms_install] Error 1
```

UPD: [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s a step missing in the instructions: you need to ensure your system is up-to-date. After the

```
sudo apt update
```

step, run

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

This should install the latest kernel; if it doesn’t, you can fix that by running

```
sudo apt install linux-image-amd64
```

Once the upgrade is complete, reboot so that your system ends up running the latest kernel. Then

```
sudo apt install build-essential libelf-dev linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

will work.